# Text alignment with pictures

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my webpage in which I want to have text wrapped on the right of it so I have some CSS like:

```
.image {
  float:left
}
```

But after reaching a certain point in the text, I want to make sure the text no longer appears to the right of the image, I want it below the image. What tag can I use to break the text onto a new line below the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the text in a div with the following styles

```
{ float:left; clear:left; }
```

The next object will appear below and to the left.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the text you want to appear below the image in a container element with a style [`clear: left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-clear) applied to it.

The [Floats section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) of the CSS specification has more details about this, including a nice example illustrating how the `clear` property works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to be able to define how much free space is below the image. Try adjusting `margin-bottom` of the image:

```
 IMG  text text text
 IMG  text text text
         text text text
         text text text
 text text text text
 text text text text
```

This way all the text may be in the same paragraph. And it will wrap around image nicely.

Then put an element with `clear:both;` style to disable wrapping after the text (just in case the text is not long enough)